# Google Analytics V4 with Amazon devices

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, amazon-appstore

I have an android app where I have been using **Google Analytics V4**, which does not require any library, but is a part of **Google Play services V4.3** and later.

So I was porting my app to the **Amazon App Store**, and Amazon devices **won't** have Google Play installed. So will Google Analytics work with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an answer to this question on the Amazon forum (copied relevant section from forum below)

http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=11294

Google Analytics is now dependent on Google play service that is not available in Fire OS. I would encourage you to integrate our Anaytics SDK in your app. Please check out the below documentation.
https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/manage/analytics

Comment: The [changelog for Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/changelog#changelog) mentions that `This does not require devices to have Google Play Services installed. When Google Play Services is not available the SDK will automatically fall back to local dispatching.`  Shouldn't that mean that `v4` should work with `Fire OS`?

Comment: It also mentions that Google Play services are not required in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ I have not tried this out yet though.